# makefile objects in subdirectory

Tags: makefile

I was asked to make my VC++ code compile on gcc, and was given a makefile which *should* compile my code in a subdirectory of the directory of this make file. The problem is that the object files are looked for in the subdirectory, but output into the makefile dir. I assume I need to add something to "-o", but I am out of my depth here.

```
include ../makefile.common

CCFLAGS += -I. -I../general -L../general

HEADERS := $(wildcard *.h) $(wildcard */*.h)

SRCS := $(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard */*.cpp)

OBJS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

DEPS=$(SRCS:.cpp=.d)

EXE=k2csv

default: $(EXE)

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJS) ../general/lib2csgeneral.a
    # ( cd ../general ; make ; )
    $(CPP) $(CCFLAGS) -o $(EXE) $(OBJS) -l2csgeneral -lmh -lm -pthread $(LDEFS)

clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(DEPS) $(EXE)

ifneq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "clean"
sinclude $(DEPS)
endif
```

The code compiles if I copy the object files, but this still irks me. Thanks for any help!

Comment: `$(CPP)` expands to `$(CC) -E`. You want `$(CXX)` instead. `CCFLAGS` should also be `CPPFLAGS` (as `-I` flag is a preprocessor flag).

Answer (score 0):

It seems I needed to add a rule for my outputs. This resolved my issue:

```
%.o: %.cpp
$(CPP) $(CCFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

**$<** replaces the input, **$@** replaces the output.